# How do I lock animeframe to exactly 1 second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I try to run the code that is posted in the JSfiddle multiple times I get different number of divs(I assume that animeframe isn't exactly finishing in 1 sec)

http://jsfiddle.net/ghjKC/133/

```
    // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
        function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
            return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();
window.cancelRequestAnimFrame = ( function() {
    return window.cancelAnimationFrame            ||
        window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame         ||
        window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame        ||
        window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame        ||
        clearTimeout
} )();

var request;

(function animloop(){
    console.log("render() should be done here and now");
    request = requestAnimFrame(animloop, $("#time").append("<div></div>"));
})();

// cancelRequestAnimFrame to stop the loop in 1sec
console.log("will do cancelRequestAnimFrame in 1sec...")
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("1sec expired doing cancelRequestAnimFrame() now")
    cancelRequestAnimFrame(request);                
}, 1*1000)
```

My question is how to ensure I get the same exact amount of divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantees regarding the precision of `setTimeout` and `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks.

`setTimeout` is quite imprecise.

`requestAnimationFrame` depends on how fast your system can render your page. If the page is very complex and the frame rate drops, the callback will be called much less than 60 times per second.

Now if you explain what your *actual* problem is, we can try to find a good solution.

You said that you want a constant number of `<div>`, which means a constant number of executions. This cannot be controlled by time. Depending on your use-case, you may control the number of executions directly. E.g. run your callback 60 times (which ideally would be close to 1s with `requestAnimationFrame`).

**EDIT**
based upon your comment: if you want to do a progress bar that fills smoothly over 1 sec. the best way to do it is this: use `requestAnimationFrame`, the first parameter passed to your callback is a high precision time. From this compute how much you should fill your progress bar. If the time > 1sec, don't request another frame.

Main idea:

```
var startTime;

function startProgress() {
  startTime = null;
  requestAnimationFrame(progress);
}

function progress(time) {
  if (startTime === null) startTime = time;
  // Compute progress since last frame
  var ratio = (time - startTime) / 1000; // time is in [ms]
  // Here you should update your progress, maybe this:
  // Note I've used Math.min because we might go over 100% due to callback time.
  $(".progressDiv").width(Math.min(ratio, 1) * 300);
  // If we're not done yet, request a new animation frame
  if (ratio < 1) requestAnimationFrame(progress);
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is something like a loading bar.I need to fill lets say 25 div long in 5 but I need to do it smooth

Comment: I've edited my post to show how you can smoothly animate a progress bar over one second.